# XSLT how to remove KML Placemark and childs tags based on Placemark attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, kml

I’m using a script in Java to populate a KML template file with some statistical data. After this operation the KML file is functioning perfectly and I can see the relative map on GIS or Google Earth . The statistical data are stored in the field “description”.

Anyway sometimes data are not available and the field is populated by the string “nodata”. I would like to set a XSL file to remove the whole placemarks with “nodata”, writing a new KML file, made only by data available placemarks . The structure of KML is the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document id="doc">
    <Schema name="Geographic_Placemarks">
      <SimpleField name="Description" type="string" />
      <SimpleField name="x" type="string" />
      <SimpleField name="y" type="string" />
    </Schema>
    <Folder>
      <name>Geographic_Placemarks</name>

         <Placemark>
        <name>Site 1</name>
        <description>nodata</description>
        <Style>
          <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
          </LineStyle>
          <PolyStyle>
            <fill>0</fill>
          </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#Geographic_Placemarks">
            <SimpleData name="x">571750    </SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="y">4548250    </SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Polygon>
          <altitudeMode>clampToGround    </altitudeMode>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <altitudeMode>clampToGround    </altitudeMode>
              <coordinates>11.1825432433631,45.6613329598511 11.1298128785963,45.7000370530753 11.1833198656477,45.6994951268141 11.1825432433631,45.6613329598511    </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
      </Placemark>

      <Placemark>
        <name>Site 2</name>
        <description>10</description>
        <Style>
          <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
          </LineStyle>
          <PolyStyle>
            <fill>0</fill>
          </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#Geographic_Placemarks">
            <SimpleData name="x">575750</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="y">4548250</SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Polygon>
          <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
              <coordinates>11.1825432433631,45.6613329598511     11.1833198656477,45.6994951268141 11.2337967406582,45.6989609013362 11.2329870100429,45.6607994408117 11.1825432433631,45.6613329598511    </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
      </Placemark>
   </Folder>
 </Document>
</kml>
```

I’ve tried to prepare a XSL file to copy all the lines of the KML file except for the placemarks with a “nodata” string description, but I’m really a newbie with XSL and probably I made a coarse mistake.

This is the XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


  <!--placemarks to be deleted-->
 <xsl:template match="kml:Placemark[kml:description = nodata]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key condition to delete the placemark is

```
<xsl:template match="kml:Placemark[kml:description = nodata]"/>
```

In this way the placemark “Site 1” should be deleted and the placemark “Site 2” should be kept.  But the result is that both the placemarks in KML are deleted.

Please can you help me in the XSL setup? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<xsl:template match="kml:Placemark[kml:description = nodata]"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="kml:Placemark[kml:description = 'nodata']"/>
```

Comment: Sorry for the uncomplete KML. Now I've completed the input. Unfortunately, the change you suggested didn't make any difference. I still have a KML with no placemarks after the modification.

Comment: great job Thank you. There was another very little sintx error. So your suggestion solved the problem. Is there any chance to trim all the spaces created by the lines cancellation?

Comment: Yes, add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to the top level of your stylesheet. And you'll probably want to add `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` too.